# Doctrine2 & zf2 : fetchAll() result to JSON ,cont convert result to array and then to json in ZF2

Tags: json, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Im completely new to Doctrine and ZF2 , coming from C# env.  from few days im working on doctrine and zf2 . and trying to learn the basic things so that I can build **RESTFull Service  API**  in coming days . Now , I am trying to get the  doctrine fetch All() result in to json but failing to do so.   mys API client ( backbone.js )  is working fine and it is  result but showing empty objects

my controller code goes like this

```
 public function getList() {

        $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Application\Entity\Test');

        $posts = $repository->findAll();

      echo var_dump((array)$posts);

      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://api.server.com');

     return new JsonModel($posts);
    }
```

var_dump result

```
array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(Application\Entity\Test)#339 (2) {
        ["id":"Application\Entity\Test":private]=>
        int(2)
        ["name":"Application\Entity\Test":private]=>
        string(5) "Kumar"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(Application\Entity\Test)#340 (2) {
        ["id":"Application\Entity\Test":private]=>
        int(1)
        ["name":"Application\Entity\Test":private]=>
        string(8) "Panindra"
      }

    }
```

and my JSONModel out put is `[{},{}]`.

I want to build this as RESTFull Service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [QueryBuilder API](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-querybuilder) and `getResult()` method of the `Doctrine\ORM\Query` object with `HYDRATE_ARRAY` option to achieve that. Example:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('t')
             ->from('Application\Entity\Test', 't');

$results = $queryBuilder->getQuery()
                        ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

return new JsonModel($results);
```

Answer (score -1):

Everything in your code is correct and works fine. The JsonModel is "empty" because your class members are private. If you set them to public, you will get the expected JsonModel.

Comment: You shouldn't use public members in Doctrine 2 entities, because of lazy loading stuff